# No color charged gluons

Tags: physics, alternate-reality, quantum, strong-force

In an alternate universe all gluons are colorless meaning that no gluons have color charge.

How would this affect the color force?

Comment: You're looking at it backwards. Colors are just a model crated to explain effects we observe. At the bottom of things as far as we know they are just some excitations in fields, like (almost?) anything else. You can have different model for the same observable effects, or you can start by imagining effects and developing model for them; simply removing model will not change facts.

Answer (score 3):

The color charges of the strong nuclear (gluonic) force were invented to build a subatomic model in which quarks did not violate the Pauli Exclusion Principle, which requires that fermions occupying the same quantum system be in different states.  (i.e. there's no "room" in a single orbital of an atom for two electrons in the same state, though this is a very specific entailment of the much broader exclusion principle.)  The simplest way to discharge the color force from quantum mechanics is therefore to jettison the Pauli Exclusion Principle.

How would the world be different without the Pauli Exclusion Principle?  Well, it's hard to say since we in fact have it, but one way you might imagine a world without it is to suppose that electrons are able to crowd atomic orbitals.  If electrons can crowd atomic orbitals, there's no real need for there to be multiple atomic orbitals at all, we could have unlimited electrons in the first orbital.  This would mean that every atom, including the really big, unstable, trans-uranic ones, would have the same radius as a hydrogen atom.  This would mean that elements would get much, much more dense as atomic number increases, because heavy elements could be much more tightly packed than they are in the actual world.

Losing multiple orbitals also breaks EVERYTHING we know about chemistry, so you're looking at a very different world.

Comment: For that matter, changing physics in such a way that the *behavior of atoms* is affected, any change is going to be reflected in a major way on the universe, I have no doubts on that.  The thing with physics is everything hinges on everything else.  In order for there not to be the Pauli Exclusion Principle and for there not to be major paradoxes, much of the universe would have to be different as a result.

Comment: It gets worse… Pauli Exclusion is due to the existence of quantum spin.  The rules *emerge*, rather than being specified.  Likewise spin just shows up because of the symmetry of spacetime (i.e. special relativity), in which Boosts do not commute (similar to what I'm explaining in my answer, but in this case you get a rotation out as well if you add boosts in different directions and represent the result as a single boost).

Comment: Yeah, in order to get rid of Pauli Exclusion spin either has to go away or be very different than it is, and messing with spin in that way probably removes baryons from the world at a minimum.  Endlessly screwed.  Better off constructing a novel physics from the ground up than trying to make such sweeping changes to actual physics.

Answer (score 2):

It would not work, period.

Gluons *match* the symmetry of the color charge.  Read up on [Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group).  You have 8 different gauge bosons corresponding to the operations in the group.  Oh, you need to know about [symmetry groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).  Seriously, you need to know this.

That last page shows a Rubik’s cube as the top illustration.
[image: cube]

So that’s a good Example to continue with.  Consider all the different possible *operations* on the cube: a minimal set would be a quarter-twist clockwise of each separate face, indicated by the unchanging color center of the face.

Thus picture shows twisting the Red face, in progress.  You can twist the opposite face (it’s a color that’s not represented in the picture, so let’s say Orange) *independently*.

But if you twist the Red face, then the Yellow face, you get a different result than if you do Yellow than Red in that order.

This non-independance, where order matters, means that the operator must leave some state change to the system.  That is why the 8 gauge bosons, the operators of the color charge’s group, **must** themselves bear a charge.

This is oversimplified, and asking about it on Physics will give you more real details.  But I want to impress upon you that it all fits together and you **cannot** arbitrarily change one part.

Consider a triangle drawn on a plane, where you know the lengths of the three sides and the three angles.  You ask “what would happen if side c was shorter?” and the answer is that you can’t since it is determined by the other sides and angles.  By analogy, the gluons are the sides and the color charge is the angles.  *Given* those angles the sides *must* be in the proper proportions for the triangle to fit together.  See [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation).

The [group involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon#Group_theory_details) in the strong force brings in, as a complete set, the colors and the gluon details.

Comment: In the triangle example it would have actually been possible for the triangle to have a side c that is shorter than it is as the other sides and angles could have been different as well.  So by the triangle analogy what else would need to be different in order for there to be no color charged gluons?

Comment: @AndersGustafson you change the angles as well.  You can’t arbitrarily change individual items.  It’s my standard it-fits-together analogy. It’s not carefully matched to the problem, but has intereresting parallels nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Well apart from any other consideration there would be no color force.

No [color force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) means we could not form [hadrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron), which means no protons, no neutrons and nothing much else.  Gluons hold hadrons together as mediators of the color field.

No protons and neutrons means no atoms either.  So a very boring universe.

To form hadrons we'd need to replace the color force with something else, which would, to get something like our universe, mean effectively reintroducing the same thing under a different name.